# Load_model and calculate accuracy for predicts

Tags: python, keras, file-upload

```
i = Input(shape=(100,100,1,))

x = Conv2D(32,(3,3),strides=1,activation='relu')(i)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)

x = Conv2D(64,(3,3),strides=1,activation='relu')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)

x = Conv2D(128,(3,3),strides=1,activation='relu')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)

x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = Dense(50, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model(i,x)
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
metrics= ['accuracy'])

train_data, test_data, train_target, test_target = 
train_test_split(data,target,test_size=0.1)

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('model_mask.h5',monitor='val_loss',verbose=0,
save_best_only=True,mode='auto')


history = model.fit(train_data,train_target,epochs=20,callbacks= 
[checkpoint],validation_data=(test_data,test_target))
```

Thats my model and model is working very well.

```
model = load_model("model_mask.h5")  

img_resp = requests.get(url=url)
img_arr = np.array(bytearray(img_resp.content),dtype=np.uint8)
img = cv2.imdecode(img_arr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
faces = face_clsfr.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5)

face_img = gray[y:y+w,x:x+w]
resized = cv2.resize(face_img,(100,100))
normalized = resized/255.0
reshaped = np.reshape(normalized,(1,100,100,1))
result = model.predict(reshaped)
```

I uploaded my trained model. Also its working its predicting mask on or off. But i want to find accuracy.
Im working with openCv and python. I trained my model and uploaded it. But now i want to calculate accuracy of camera's snapshots? how can i code ?

Comment: You'll never get an answer if you don't provide sufficient information, what your model is, what your images are, what your task is...

Comment: okay i m going to edit

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the classification metrics you need a test set of images. Then you'll need to record the predicted and true labels for all of the images in your test set. After you've done all that you'll be able to calculate whatever metrics you want.

Comment: So you are talking about, I have to  evaluate before save the model ? But i cant solve the code?

Comment: No, you can evaluate offline you just need to run predictions on a test set....

Comment: how cani evaulate offline. im taking precitions my code is working but i want to when camera find a face, Find out how accurately you wear a mask

Comment: You would have to measure that ahead of time, show it a bunch of still images and count true positives, true negatives, etc.

Comment: im sorry for my english. i cant understand you. I trained model with about 4000 images. Then i save it this model. Now i open new project and load model. its okay. Then i took the snapshots in camera. And model is predicting very well. Now i want to just see the accuracy for these snapshots

Comment: I hope you aren't evaluating on you train set....https://towardsdatascience.com/train-validation-and-test-sets-72cb40cba9e7

Comment: i know how can i evaluate with test set. But i cant understand when i evaulate the model, how can i reach the accuracy and calculate prediction accuracy with model = load_model("...") ?